# ¿Cómo usar los elementos de un ArrayList de una clase en otra?

Tags: java, arraylist

Necesito usar los elementos de un `ArrayList` que he creado en una clase en otra distinta. He intentado varios métodos como el `.clone` y nada me funciona.
Tengo esto en una clase, toda la parte donde añado elementos al `ArrayList` la he omitido.

```
public class listaTrabajadoresEmpresa {

    public static void main (String [] args){

        ArrayList<Departamento> listaDepartamentos = new ArrayList<Departamento>();
        ArrayList<Empleado> listaEmpleados = new ArrayList<Empleado>();
```

Luego en otra clase distinta necesitaria que lo que pongo a continuación hiciera uso del `ArrayList` de la otra clase:

```
public class eliminarTrabajadoresEmpresa{


public static void main (String args[]){

for(Empleado empleadoActual: listaEmpleados){

    System.out.println("idEmpleado: "+empleadoActual.getIdEmpleado()+","+" Nombre: "+empleadoActual.getNombre()+","+
            " Apellidos: "+empleadoActual.getApellidos()+","+" Trabajo: "+empleadoActual.getTrabajo()+","+" Salario: "+empleadoActual.getSalario()+
            ","+" Departamento: "+empleadoActual.getNombreDepartamento());
}
```

Comment: Crea una clase para TrabajadoresEmpresa, que incluya el arraylist y desde donde quieras llamarle creas el objeto, y añades o eliminas a tu antojo. Te recomendaria leer algo de Programación Orientada a Objetos porque crear dos clases con un metodo main para añadir o eliminar empleados no tiene sentido. Deberías de crear la clase Trabajadores que tuviese un metodo para añadir y eliminar trabajadores del arraylist y desde otra clase con el main llamar a los metodos que quieras

Answer (score 1):

Deberías tener una clase `Empleado` con los datos de los empleados (id, nombre, apellidos...).

```
public class Empleado{
 private int idEmpleado;
 private String nombre;
 private String apellidos;

 public Empleado(int id, String nombre, String apellidos){
     this.idEmpleado=id;
     this.nombre=nombre;
     this.apellidos=apellidos;
    }
```

Con esto ya podría crear objetos `Empleado`. Después deberías tener una clase `Empresa` o como quieras llamarla en la cual definas los métodos y `ArrayLists` que quieras utilizar:

```
  public class Empresa{
      private ArrayList<Empleado> empleados;

      public Empresa(){}          

      public ArrayList getEmpleados(){
       empleados = new ArayList<Empleado>();
       //Aquí escribes el código con el que quieras rellenar la ArrayList
       return empleados;
       }

     }
```

y ahora, para obtener la `ArrayList` de empleados, en tu método main escribes lo siguiente:

```
    public class listaTrabajadoresEmpresa {
    private Empresa empresa = new Empresa();


public static void main (String [] args){


        ArrayList<Empleado> listaEmpleados = empresa.getEmpleados();
}
}
```

Comment: Si, se que no se puede tener mas de 1 clase main, pero este ejercicio es una practica "colaborativa" y nos lo han dividido asi, de ahi la duda al itnentar llevar un arraylist de un sitio al otro.
Y si, tenemos las clases Empleado y Departamento creadas aparte.

Comment: Bien, si entiendes esas prácticas borro el primer apartado. ¿lo demás te sirve? @Rodrigo

Comment: La clase "eliminarTrabajadoresEmpresa" (que parece el nombre de un método y no de una clase) debería de llamarse Empresa, puesto que estas haciendo debajo un constructor public Empresa(){}

Comment: @AlvaroLopez-Pupila1992 se me ha olvidado ponerlo en alguna parte? Lo siento si es así pero he llamado bien a la clase creo

Comment: No, parece ser que al ser incompatible y tan restringido no se puede hacer, porque no podemos añadir otra clase mas donde meter eso que me has dicho. Yo supongo que lo que queria el profesor es que cada uno hiciesemos nuestra clase con atributos, metodos y constructores y la clase main con el resto de cosas que piden, y mas que funcionase todo en conjunto que sepamos hacer lo que pide.
Gracias a todos aun asi por la ayuda!!

Comment: @Erlantz Calvo Un constructor se tiene que llamar igual que la clase. Me refería a que has hecho una "clase" (lo pongo entre comillas por el nombre que tiene) que se llama eliminarTrabajadoresEmpresa y en ella haces public Empleado... cuando seria public eliminarTrabajadoresEmpresa